# Auto fill a table after creation jpa

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I want to populate the table after his generation from the `@Entity` Class.
I want to know if this is possible with `JPA` and how  can I do it .

Comment: Populate the database with what?  The DDL to create the database gets executed when the context is created, so you can populate the database  with what ever you need when you first create the context.  Or are you looking to have JPA execute another script with insert statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Hibernate has @`Generated` annotation but JPA doesn't have it and there is no alternative to it. You can also try to apply @`PrePersist` annotation before `EntityManager` persists your object.